# Difference between Linq (from var in Something where ... select var) and Something.Where(...) in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I'm optimizing part of large application that use Entity Framework 4.1 (upgrade to EF 5 or 6 is not possible), and I noticed something odd...

I have the following code:

```
var fromPromAction = PromotionActionSync.GetEntities(user, context, pkg).Where(x => x.PromotionConditionId.HasValue).Select(x => x.PromotionCondition);

var res = fromPromAction.Union(promotionConditions);

var someList = res.ToList();
```

Theoretically, both fromPromAction and promotionConditions are IQuerable but ToList throws: "This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."

I know this means that Linq is attempting to mix in memory collection and database collection but I don't understand where and why... after some research I found out that this:

```
var fromPromAction2 = (from a in PromotionActionSync.GetEntities(user, context, pkg)
                  join b in context.PromotionConditions on a.PromotionConditionId equals b.Id
                  select b);

var res2 = fromPromAction2.Union(promotionConditions);

var someList2 = res2.ToList();
```

Works without error, also while the first code throw when I try to extract sql like this:

```
var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)res).ToTraceString();
```

The second works without a problem.

Why is that? I thought that this:

```
var someVar = (from item in SomeContext.Items where item.Id > 10 select item.SomeProperty);
```

Is equal to

```
var someVar = SomeContext.Items..Where(x => x.Id > 10).Select(x => x.SomeProperty);
```

Is it different when using Entity Framework?

Comment: I'd guess that `promotionConditions` in the first example is a List/Array, not an IQueryable connected to an EF Context. This means you are trying to merge a list with query results. How is this variable created?

Comment: Why do you have both `PromotionConditionId` and `PromotionCondition`? Shouldn't the first query be `var fromPromAction = PromotionActionSync.GetEntities(user, context, pkg).Where(x => x.PromotionCondition != null).Select(x => x.PromotionCondition);`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:

PromotionCondition is created by very complex query - but It is not the problem since I can convert it to SQL without a problem - fromPromAction (the first one, that is) seems to be a problem - since it throws when I try to get SQL out of it

Comment: @dasblinkenlight:

As far as I can see - using what You suggested makes "AND ([Extent1].[PromotionConditionId] IS NOT NULL)" condition the first one, but doesn't change the query result - I guess they are both correct.

Comment: The various queries are *not* equivalent, but the error is *very* specific. It can occur *only* if the first query touches a variable that *isn't* a Linq to Entities IQueryable. What is the type of `promotionConditions`? Either it's a plain IEnumerable<> or its own query touches an IEnumerable and raises the exception, not `fromPromAction`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:

Sorry for late comment - as far as I can see promotionConditions is IQueryable<PromotionCondition> (as it should be), and as I said earlier - I can get the - 300 line long (yeah... I know...) Sql out of it. On the other hand when I try to get Sql out of fromPromotionAction - it throws "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[PromotionCondition]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'" so it would seem it is IEnumerable (even though, according to debugger it is IQueryable...)